# How to prevent <hr> from creating a space between two divs?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so here's the code

```css
.div1 {
  background-color:skyblue;
  font-family:Verdana;
  text-align:right;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.div2 {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  font-family:Verdana;
  text-align:left;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <h1>Hey</h1>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="div2">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3d25mpv/)

As you can see, I tried to put a hr between the two `div`s. This is good, except for the white space around the black line that I want. I know it's supposed to be like this, but is there a way to get just the black line?

Comment: `hr{margin: 0;}` - http://jsfiddle.net/3d6csL9h/

Comment: Seems complicated, why not style the bottom of ine of the divs with a border?

Comment: I use `*{margin:0;padding:0}` to avoid those problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple use `margin: 0` to `hr` element:

```
hr{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.div1 {
    background-color:skyblue;
    font-family:Verdana;
    text-align:right;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.div2 {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    font-family:Verdana;
    text-align:left;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
hr {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
     <h1>Hey</h1>

</div>
<hr>
<div class="div2">
     <h1>Hello</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Which "default css" are you talking about? That isn't in the (not normative) [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) section of CSS 2.1 spec.

Comment: not really sure where w3schools took it from (again), but they seem to be the only ones stating that, have a look at http://www.w3fools.com/...